# SQL query to use group by to get the sum of two different columns within a date range

Tags: sql

I have two tables time track and absence for  an employee.

```
person_number  Measure        start_Date    end_date           Time_type
73636           10            01-Jan-2020     02-Jan-2020        Double
73636           24            06-Jan-2020     08-jan-2020        Double
73636           10            15-Jan-2020     25-Jan-2020        Regular Pay
73636           11.9          06-Jan-2020     08-jan-2020        Double
73636           27            10-Jan-2020     15-Jan-2020        Regular Pay
```

Absence det

```
person_number         start_Date    end_date         duration       Absence_type
73636              05-Jan-2020     10-Jan-2020       10              Vacation
73636              06-Jan-2020     18-jan-2020          9          Paid Leave 
73636              20-Jan-2020     21-jan-2020          1         Paid Leave
```

Now when i pass the from and to date as 01-Jan-2020 and 31-Jan-2020, the output should look like -

```
Person_Number   Double    Regular     Hour_code        hour_amount
73636           31.9      37          Paid Leave   10
```

The hour_code should have only "Paid Leave" and no other absences

Now I have written the below query for this

```
SELECT
  distinct person_number,
  sum(
    CASE
      WHEN elements = 'Double' THEN measure
    END
  ) AS OT_Hours,
  sum(
    CASE
      WHEN elements LIKE 'Regular Pay%' THEN measure
    END
  ) AS regular_measure_hours,
  sum(
    CASE
      WHEN absence_name IN ('Paid Leave') THEN absence_duration
    END
  ) AS hour3_amount,
  max(
    CASE
      WHEN absence_name IN ('Paid Leave') THEN 'Paid Leave'
    END
  ) AS hour3_code
FROM
  (
    select
      person_number,
      Time_type elements,
      Absence_type absence_name,
      duration,
      measure
    from
      time_track_tab,
      abs_tab,
      per_all_people_F papf
    where
      time_track_tab.person_id = abs_tab.person_id
      and abs_tab.person_id = papf.person_id
      and abs_tab.Absence_type = 'Paid Leave'
  )
group by
  person_number
```

This is giving me multiple row output and calculation of sum is not coming correctly as in between the to and from date there are different dates present for both absence and time track.

My requirement is to calculate the sum of ALL the duration and measure column within these parameter dates. How can i tweak my query to get the correct sum between these dates ?

Is there a way to use partition by or group by or anything  else to calculation these correctly in the column

Comment: what is the time_tab column? Another alternative would be to use group by instead of distict.

Comment: It was my bad. Comoon link is person_id and I have added group by still getting the same error

Comment: @jwzinserl is there a better way to use the group by in this query ?

Comment: I would consider doing the aggregation before joining the tables because that way data won't get duplicated when joining by person_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to group both tables first then join them together to avoid the cross join.

```
select person_number, TimeTrack.DoublePay, TimeTrack.Regular,
Absenses.Hour_code, Absenses.hour_amount from 
per_all_people_F papf,
(select
  person_id, sum(duration) as hour_amount, Absence_type as Hour_code
  from
  abs_tab
  where
  abs_tab.Absence_type = 'Paid Leave'
  and
  start_Date between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-31'
  group by person_id,Absence_type
) Absenses,
(select 
  person_id,
  sum(case when Time_type = 'Double' then Measure end) as DoublePay,
  sum(case when Time_type = 'Regular Pay' then Measure end) as Regular
  from time_track_tab
  where
  start_Date between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-31'
  group by person_id
) TimeTrack
where
papf.person_id = TimeTrack.person_id
and
papf.person_id = Absenses.person_id
and
papf.person_id = 73636
```

I made a SqlFiddle if you want to play with it
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03e460/36
Also my 2 cents; I'd recommend left outer joining from the per_all_people_F table or else people without absenses will get filtered out.

Comment: If i do sum inside the subquery like here, then it is calculating the sum for all the person numbers and showing that.

Comment: You could filter to only one person by adding ` and papf.person_id = 73636` to the outer where clause. I updated my answer if you wanted to filter to one person

Comment: no actually i need to run for around 500 employees. the subquery should only work for the employee that the db is processing

Answer (score 1):

See if, what you need is something like this:

```
select * from 
(SELECT person_number,
    sum(
        CASE
            WHEN Time_type = 'Double' THEN measure
        END
    ) AS Double,
    sum(
        CASE
            WHEN Time_type = ('Regular Pay') THEN measure
        END
        ) AS regular
    from time_track_tab
    group by person_number
) A
inner join 
(SELECT
    person_number,
    sum(
        CASE
            WHEN Absence_type = 'Vacation' THEN duration
        END
    ) AS Vacation,
    sum(
        CASE
            WHEN Absence_type = ('Paid Leave') THEN duration
        END
    ) AS paidLeave
    from abs_tab
    group by person_number
)B on A.person_number = B.person_number
```

here the fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/21253/2